# How to add future feature data to STS model - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series

I went through [this case study](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Structural_Time_Series_Modeling_Case_Studies_Atmospheric_CO2_and_Electricity_Demand) of Structural Time Series Modeling in TensorFlow, but I couldn't find a way to add future values of features. I would like to add holidays effect, but when I am following these steps my holidays starts to repeat in forecast period.

Below is visualisation from case study, you can see that temperature_effect starts from begginig.

[image]

Is it possible to feed the model with actual future data?

Edit:
In my case holidays started to repeat in my forecast which does not make sense.
Just now I have found [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/343) on github refering to this problem, there is workaround to this problem.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Are you attempting to replicate the case study or is this your own data? Note in the case study, the output is essentially the sum of all 'effects'. See code chunk in model and fitting.  If you want to feed a model with future data, the only possiblity would be to fit a prediction of data into your model. Many methods exist for this and depends on your application. Reading on RNN would probably be a good start.

Comment: This is case study data only to show that temperature data is repeated. So if I understand correct, it is impossible to feed a model with future data using this STS model?

Comment: Based on your explanation, no...you can't put future data into your model because it does not exist (future). But you can predict the future and feed that into your model through a feedback loop. See https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series See the section on autoregressive predictions. Thats 'feeding' the future into your prediction.

Comment: Yes, I have also seen this. I wanted to know if it is possible in STS model. Thanks. Since there is no other better answer, you can post yours, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight fallacy in what you are asking in particular. As mentioned in my comment when predicting with a model, future data does not exist because it just hasn't happened yet. For whatever model its not possible to feed data that does not exist. However you could use an autoregressive approach as defined in the link above to feed 'future' data. A Pseudo example would be as follows:

Model 1: STS model with inputs x_in and x_future to predict y_future.

You could stack this with a secondary helper model that predicts x_future from x_in.

Model 2: Regression model with input x_in predicting x_future.

Concatenating these models will result then allow your STS model to take into account 'future' feature elements. On the other hand in your question you mention a holiday effect. You could simply add another input where you define via some if/else case if a holiday effect is active or inactive. You could also use random sampling of your holiday effect as well and it might help. To exactly help you with code/model to do what you want I'll need to have more details on your model/inputs/outputs.

In simple words, you can't work with data that doesn't exist so you either need to spoof it or get it in some other way.

Comment: In my question, I am reffering to holidays effect as a "future" data and I think it is something we know... I have added picture in edit. I have also found answer on github.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial on forecasting is here：https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Structural_Time_Series_Modeling_Case_Studies_Atmospheric_CO2_and_Electricity_Demand

You only need to enter new data and parameters to predict how many results in the future.

Comment: I have seen this tutorial, I have even added this link in my question.

Comment: demand_forecast_dist = tfp.sts.forecast(
    model=demand_model,
    observed_time_series=demand_training_data,
    parameter_samples=q_samples_demand_,
    num_steps_forecast=num_forecast_steps) -->>>>>>num_forecast_steps

Comment: My question was how to feed model with future data, not how to specify number of steps to predict.

Comment: [demand_training_data] This is the data parameter of your future retraining model.

Comment: This is a complete official case：https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.13.0/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Structural_Time_Series_Modeling_Case_Studies_Atmospheric_CO2_and_Electricity_Demand.ipynb

Comment: this is not the answer, `demand_training_data` refers to observed_time_series. It is not future data.